# Using regex to find block containing a certain word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find blocks like these using regex.
An example of the code I'm trying to find is shown bellow,

```
entity //This is what I want to select
{
    "id" "2"
    "classname" "light"   //This is what it should contain
    "_light" "255 255 255 200"
    "_lightHDR" "-1 -1 -1 1"
    "_lightscaleHDR" "1"
    "_quadratic_attn" "1"
    "origin" "-128 0 -128"
    editor
    {
        "color" "220 30 220"
        "visgroupshown" "1"
        "visgroupautoshown" "1"
        "logicalpos" "[0 0]"
    }
}
```

How would I go forward finding this block?
Blocks not containing **"classname" "light"** should not be selected. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: is it classname fix and light variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
entity\s*\{[^}]*"classname" "light"[^}]*\}\s*\}
```

The key term here is `[^}]*`, which ensures the match doesn't run over to the next block.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/4zKAts3v3x) of this regex in action with your example and a non-matching example.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Regex is pretty confusing if you don't have experience with it.

Comment: @mats it's worth learning. You would be surprised how many occasions you can use it and save yourself lots of code.

Comment: I know this is a very late reply, but I just wanted to thank you for encouraging me to learn regex. It has helped so much since I posted this. Thank you!